# How to pass session data in different controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have the following method in my `verify_logins`controller:

```
function checkLogInInfo() {
    if ($_POST) {
        $v = $this->input->post('user_id');
        $vldata['password'] = $this->input->post('password');

        $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT e.id FROM user u LEFT JOIN employee e ON u.user_id = e.id WHERE e.emp_id = '$v' ")->result_array();

        if (empty($query1)) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Invalid ID or Password');
            redirect('verify_logins/index');
        } else {
            $vldata = array();
            $vldata['user_id'] = $query1[0]['id'];

            $temp = $vldata['user_id'];
            $query2 = $this->db->query("SELECT e.emp_name FROM user u LEFT JOIN employee e ON u.user_id = e.id WHERE e.id ='$temp' ")->result_array();

            $vldata['user_name'] = $query2[0]['emp_name'];

            $this->session->set_userdata($vldata['user_name']);
            redirect('admin_logins/index');
        }
    } else {
        redirect('verify_logins/index');
    }
}
```

The above method checks my login data and logs in to the home page of my application.

Now I have another controller named `admin_logins` with the following method:

```
public function index() {
    $data["message"] = $this->session->flashdata('message');
    $data["user_name"] = $this->session->userdata($vldata['user_name']);
    $this->load->view('admin_logins/index', $data);
}
```

The above method loads the home page of my application.

I'm trying to load the username of the logged in user in the home page. I'm trying to pass the username from method `checkLogInInfo()` of controller verify_logins() to method `index()` of controller `admin_logins()` by using `session`, but can't figure out the right way to do it. I can guess that I have some syntax problem in my `index()` method of the controller. I need help regarding the correct syntax and way to do it.

The portion of my view page where I'm trying to display the username is:

```
<p class="f-right">User: <strong><?php if(isset($user_name)){echo "Welcome, ".$user_name;} ?></strong></p>
```

And the error I'm getting is this:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: vldata
```

P.S. I've loaded the session library in both controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the user name as like

```
$this->session->set_userdata('user_name',$vldata['user_name']);
```

And while you are retrieving give as

```
$data["user_name"] = $this->session->userdata('user_name');
```

You have to pass the session variable name as first parameter while setting the session data so that you can use the same key to retrieve the session data.For more read [**this**](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: There is something wrong with either my PC or my browser for which I can't read anything in the CI User Guide for the past few days. That's why I couldn't go through this earlier. +1 for excellent answer and explanation. It's all crystal clear to me now.