# Codeigniter session not working in another controller when using xampp

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, xampp

I created a Codeignier controller for testing, my controller using codeigniter session library:

**Test.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends CI_Controller {

     function __construct()
     {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->config->load('config');
       $this->load->helper("url");

     }


    function index()
    {
        $newdata = array(
            'username'  => 'uname',
            'email'     => 'uname@some-site.com'
            );

        $this->session->set_userdata('testsession', $newdata);
        redirect("https://mysite/index.php/test/getSession");
    }

    function getSession()
    {
        var_dump($this->session->userdata('testsession'));

    }

}
```

Session library is loaded in Codeigniter's autoload.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

This code was working good in my web server with Apache + PHP 7.1 and MySQL, but not working with xampp 7.1.1 in Windows. Codeignitor sessions not work in getSession function when using xampp.

My Codeigniter config file is default and I checked PHP's TimeZone.

Comment: You can try change encryption key in config.php file line number 317.you have to mention some string in the $config['encryption_key'] = 'your key';. its user defined

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to load the config/config.php file as it's all ready loaded.

Make sure you have set your sessions something like this I my self created a session folder in system so it is more protected. Set the folder permission 0700

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 1440;
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'storage/session/'; 
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

Note

```
EXT: The PHP file extension
FCPATH: Path to the front controller (this file) (root of CI)
SELF: The name of THIS file (index.php)
BASEPATH: Path to the system folder
APPPATH: The path to the "application" folder
```

Autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');

$autoload['helper'] = array('form', 'url');
```

Controller

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        // Autoload the url helper in config/autoload.php
        $this->load->helper("url");
    }

    function index() {

        $newdata = array(
            'username' => 'uname',
            'email' => 'uname@some-site.com'
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata('testsession', $newdata);

        $session_data = $this->getSession();

        $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];

        $data['email'] = $session_data['email'];

        $this->load->view('test_view', $data);
    }

    function getSession()
    {
        return $this->session->userdata('testsession');

    }

}
```

Then on the views / test_view.php

```
<?php echo $username;?>

<?php echo $email;?>
```

Using the redirect() https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#redirect

Comment: Tks wolfgang, but i'm trying get session data from another function. In my case, i set a some data in session from index() function and i want to use this data in testsession(). Something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26843009/how-to-pass-session-data-in-different-controller-in-codeigniter, It worked in my web server but not working in xampp (localhost)